# HttpURLConnection getInputStream: timeout always after 180 seconds

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to download a file on very slow connection in this way:

```
    java.net.URL url = new URL("https://X.X.X.X:8443/path/2f6b88cf2b70ee933197edfc9627a9bc/");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)  url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(240 * 1000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(240 * 1000);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Files.copy(connection.getInputStream(), new File("test.zip").toPath());
    System.out.println("Time: "+((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000) + " sec.");
```

and I noticed that for some reasons (native windows socket timeout?) it always breaks after **180** seconds of downloading without any exceptions.

Timeout set in setConnectTimeout(...) or setReadTimeout(...) doesn't help.

I tried to download that file using wget:

```
wget https://X.X.X.X:8443/path/2f6b88cf2b70ee933197edfc9627a9bc/ --no-check-certificate
--2015-09-07 14:36:12--  https://X.X.X.X:8443/path/2f6b88cf2b70ee933197edfc9627a9bc/
Connecting to X.X.X.X:8443... connected.
WARNING: The certificate of ‘X.X.X.X’ is not trusted.
WARNING: The certificate of ‘X.X.X.X’ hasn't got a known issuer.
The certificate's owner does not match hostname ‘X.X.X.X’
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://X.X.X.X:8443/files/test.zip [following]
--2015-09-07 14:36:16--  https://X.X.X.X:8443/files/test.zip
Reusing existing connection to X.X.X.X:8443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 321917584 (307M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘test.zip’

test.zip                                  100%[====================================================================================>] 307.00M   253KB/s   in 19m 50ss
```

Complete file was successfully saved on disk after 20 minutes.

What is wrong with HttpURLConnection?

Edit:
I tried to download test file from other server by http protocol and everything was OK. It seems to be a server or protocol specific problem. But why wget manages to download whole file?

Edit2: following your advices I also tried:

- remove connection.setDoOutput(true);
- use direct link to avoid redirection 302
- replace Files.copy method by custom implementation

Unfortunately none of above helps.

Edit3:
I noticed that file is also available on the same server via unsecure http protocol. So I changed only the URL in my code and  after **120** seconds I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3066)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3060)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:2735)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:2854)
```

Comment: My understanding of readTimeout is that the amount of time to wait till data is available. Anyhow, they are in milli seconds, and you have given 240,000 - 4 minutes.

Comment: I tried decrease both timeouts to 10s or increase to 10m but it always interrupts after 180s.

Comment: Could you post the complete stacktrace of the observed exception?

Comment: @LittleSanti I should mentioned that there is no any exception. Program exits normally.

Comment: @tomek.ceszke From the wget output - there is a 302 redirection. Instead of using the current URL can you tryout with the redirected URL and see what happens?

Comment: @KDM Just checked, it didn't help. HttpURLConnections follows redirections correctly.

Comment: @tomek.ceszke If there is no explicit error, what is the eventual content of file `test.zip`?

Comment: @tomek.ceszke Is this code you are trying is part of a larger program or a standalone one? Files.copy returns the number of bytes copied. Can you print that value?

Comment: @KDM `Copied 209747968 bytes in 180 sec` Original size is 307 MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution here [It is not possible to download large files at Jetty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076899/it-is-not-possible-to-download-large-files-at-jetty-server) (thanks again StackOverflow). Problem was on the server side.

Jetty 9.2 which we used has a bug that interrupts serving large files on slow connections (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472621). It seems that exception is not always thrown.

Wget and browsers somehow were able to finish downloading despite stalled transfer or connection reset. Unfortunately my Java application was more sensitive...

Upgrade bundled Jetty to the last stable version 9.3.3 fixed all problems with downloads.

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Here you are intending to do an HTTP GET.

```
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Here you are changing it to PUT.

```
Files.copy(connection.getInputStream(), new File("test.zip").toPath());
```

Here you are getting the input stream without ever having written anything. The server is still waiting for the POST data that you are never sending, so it is never sending a reponse, so you're timing out.

Lose the `setDoOutput(true);` line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't help.

Comment: You'll have to show what you did. Edit it into your question.